# How to strip hashtag from a string using python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have a lot of lines like that have 2 words with numbers separated by `#` like this: `Test#willwork`

What I want to get out of it is just the first part of the string
Using the `.split` command works fine but seems to be not working for #

Here is an example

```
finalRow['Target Sector CSR'] = mappingDict[str(guidNewTg)]['Site'].split("#")[0]
```

Comment: works for me... `'hello#hello'.split('#')`

Comment: can you print mappingDict[str(guidNewTg)]['Site'] and put here the result of this print please?

Comment: Hi @omri_saadon I'm running it now, will get back with the results in few min.

Comment: Well, @omri_saadon its not printing anything.. but still brings back on the CSV output file a raw with the word None

Comment: i think you have a problem with the access to your data.. debug your code, first see what mappingDict holds, if it holds everything it should holds then move on to mappingDict[str(guidNewTg)] and again check if it holds everything it should hold, if yes then move on.. this way you can see why you got none instead of your data.

Comment: @Darkdeamon, if you are getting None it has nothing to do with the code you have provided

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes you right its something related to the SQL query that builds the dictionary which i also struggle to understand as  its look OK on the SQL query but not when running the script